# How do you change the default O.S.?

Tags: dual-boot

How do you change the default O.S. in the grub, so that windows will boot if Ubuntu is not chosen?

Comment: Do you mean default entry as Windows? When GRUB appears Ubuntu must be highlighted and gets booted up after a certain time (10s in most cases) if no action is done. I think you want to do the same for windows. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to have GRUB remember the last boot choice made at the GRUB menu.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change/add the following lines near the top of the file...

`GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`    # change an existing line to this

`GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` # add this line

Then...

`sudo update-grub` # update the GRUB menu

`reboot` # reboot the system